# How to write a graph from matplotlib to an excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a pie graph using matplotlib.pyplot in python and would now like to take this graph and export it to an excel file in its own sheet.

What is the process of actually saving a graph as part of writing to an excel file.

If it helps at all, this is the link I followed to create my plot
https://python-graph-gallery.com/163-donut-plot-with-subgroups/

Thanks

Comment: this question is a little bit broad, but here are some examples: https://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/

Comment: What is the process of converting the chart to the .xlsx file type as used in this link?

Comment: what do you mean, if you automatically want to write an chart in an excel sheet, you have to make a graph with fits to the excel graphs, If you have another chart you can save your figure as jpeg or whatever and then need to manually adjust it

Comment: In the link that @PV8 provided the chart is not actually produced by matplotlib, but from within Excel. Can you clarify what you want to do? Do you want a picture of your matplotlib figure inside of Excel?